# Laravel validate multiple exclusive requires

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to do some complex field validations and I don't seem to be able to find a solution for this.

I have three fields:

> `field_a` (Boolean)
>   `field_b` (String)
>   `field_c` (String)

I need to validate that if `field_a` is **true** then `field_b` OR `field_c` are **not empty**.

I've tried to do something like:

```
'field_b' => 'required_with:field_a|required_if:field_c,',
'field_c' => 'required_with:field_a|required_if:field_b,',
```

But this way makes both fields required if `field_a` has been passed to the request.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to use Laravel's built-in validation system to do this kind of validation so I have created my own custom rule. I leave it here just in case somebody finds it useful.

```
class IfXOR implements Rule {
    private $required;
    private $fields;
    /**
    * Create a new rule instance.
    *
    * @param bool $required
    * @param mixed $fields
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($required, $fields) {
        $this->required = $required;
        $this->fields = $fields;
    }

    /**
    * Determine if the validation rule passes.
    *
    * @param  string  $attribute
    * @param  mixed  $value
    * @return bool
    */
    public function passes($attribute, $value) {
        if(!$this->required) return true;
        if(!is_array($this->fields)) return $value || !empty($this->fields);
        return $value || !empty(array_filter(function($f) { return !empty($f); }, $this->fields));
    }

    /**
    * Get the validation error message.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function message() {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```